# Replacing values in one matrix with values from another

Tags: r, matrix, comparison

I'm trying to compare to matrices.  When the values aren't equivalent then I want to use the value from `mat2` so long as it is greater than 0; if it is zero, then I want the value from `mat1`. As the code is currently, it appears to constantly return the value of `mat1`.

Here is my attempt:

```
mat.data1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
mat1 <- matrix(data = mat.data1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)


mat.data2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1)
mat2 <- matrix(data = mat.data2, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

mat3 = if(mat1 == mat2){mat1} else {if(mat2>0){mat2} else {mat1}}
```

the expected output should be

```
1   0   1   1   1
0   1   2   1   1
1   1   2   2   0
1   1   1   2   2
1   1   1   0   1
```

Comment: Please edit your question for style. Right now it's hard to read. Take some time to read up on how to use the interface.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- coalesce(replace(mat2, !mat2, NA), replace(mat1, !mat1, NA))    
replace(out, is.na(out), 0)
```

Or as @Axeman mentioned

```
coalesce(out, 0)
```

Comment: Last line can also be `coalesce(out, 0)`, if you're using `coalesce` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one potential way to do it.

```
mat.data1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
mat1 <- matrix(data = mat.data1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)


mat.data2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1)
mat2 <- matrix(data = mat.data2, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)


mat3 <- mat1
to_change <- which(mat2 != mat1 & mat2 > 0)
mat3[to_change] <- mat2[to_change]
```

This specific use of `which` essentially asks for the locations in `mat2` that are not equal to that in `mat1` AND where `mat2` is greater than zero. You can then just do a subset and place those values in `mat3`.

This output is then:

```
> mat3
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    2    1    1
[3,]    1    1    2    2    0
[4,]    1    1    1    2    2
[5,]    1    2    1    0    1
```